# Can someone explain/give a breakdown of this shell parameter substitution? ${cfg+-f "$cfg"}

Tags: bash, shell, tmux, variable-substitution

I was looking for a good workaround for keeping my `.tmux.conf` file consistent across systems (I have both OS X and Ubuntu and they have different techniques for copy/paste support) when I came across this comment that offered a solution: https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/issues/8#issuecomment-4134987

But before I use the code snippet in the comment, I'd like to fully understand what it's doing. In particular, I don't quite understand the last line, and the [bash man page for parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) didn't help much.

This is the line:

```
exec /path/to/actual/tmux ${cfg+-f "$cfg"} "$@"
```

Specifically, what does the `${cfg+-f "$cfg"}` part mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means to skip the parameter if it is not set. In effect resulting in one of:

```
exec /path/to/actual/tmux -f "/some/cfg" "$@"
exec /path/to/actual/tmux "$@"
```

So if `$cfg` is set, `-f "$cfg"` is used, otherwise nothing, so tmux does not complain about a missing parameter for `-f`.

Answer (score 1):

It means that if the variable `cfg` is set, it would expand with the combined value of `-f "$cfg"`.

Example:

```
> a=1234
> echo "${a+b}" # => variable is set
b
> a=
> echo "${a+b}" # => empty but still set would still expand it.
b
> unset a
> echo "${a+b}" # => it's now unset so no output
(nothing)
```

Another with an extra variable:

```
> a=1234
> x=y
> echo "${a+b "$x"}"
b y
> echo "${a+"$a $x"}"
1234 y
```